# Enumerations in C++ with raw values?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have raw values for Enumerations in C++?

Swift Example:

```
enum AnOperations: String {
    case Addition = "+"
    case Subtraction = "-"
    case Division = "/"
}

// if or switch
if AnOperations.Addition.rawValue == "+" {
    print("true")
}
```

Comment: What is a "raw value"?

Comment: In C, enums have to be assigned to a int (I believe). In Swift, you can assign it to a string, a character, or a value of any integer or floating-point type. Is this possible for C++ for a string and can it be used to be compared with another string (ie if Addition (an enum) == "+")

Comment: Your example is using strings made of a single character. If you change them to characters (‘+’ instead of “+”) it will work because characters are integers. If you need strings, you will have to put them in a string-function map.

Comment: What you're looking for is a std::unordered_map perhaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must admit that I don't know anything about `Swift` except its name.

In C++, strings may not be used in enumerations.

**[Enumeration Declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)**:

> An enumeration is a distinct type whose value is restricted to a range of values (see below for details), which may include several explicitly named constants ("enumerators"). The values of the constants are values of an **integral** type known as the underlying type of the enumeration.

(Emphasize mine.)

What might work:

```
enum AnOperations: char {
  Addition = '+',
  Subtraction = '-',
  Division = '/'
};
```

because `char` is one of the integral types.

Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  enum AnOperations: char {
    Addition = '+',
    Subtraction = '-',
    Division = '/'
  };
  std::string text = "1 + 2";
  std::istringstream in(text);
  int arg1, arg2, result; char op;
  in >> arg1 >> op >> arg2;
  switch (op) {
    case Addition: result = arg1 + arg2; break;
    case Subtraction: result = arg1 - arg2; break;
    case Division: result = arg1 / arg2; break;
    default:
      std::cerr << "Unknown op. '" << op << "'!\n";
      return 1;
  }
  std::cout << arg1 << ' ' << op << ' ' << arg2 << " = " << result << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 + 2 = 3
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/804a813c75b86bd2)

Comment: is there a way to check if the enum "value" exists? (ie AnOperations.contains("+")?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I remember roughly a nice  Q/A about this but I've to dig a little bit.

Comment: That would be great! Thank you!

Comment: @HelloWorld I found this: [SO: How to check if enum value is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969304/7478597). How to ensure that all `enum` values are considered in `switch()`? That's not easy - not supported by language itself. I remember that `gcc` has  a warning for this which can be enabled.

Comment: hmm, good to know! Worst case, I'll continue using if statements.

Comment: @HelloWorld Even with the limitations of `enum` and `switch`, I would prefer them over `if`/`else` cascades. (The latter look even ugly, don't they?) The `default` branch of `switch` is fine to catch anything which is not a valid `char` in your case. That it doesn't appear in `enum` is practical no problem.

Comment: So you guessed right, I'm building a calculator. I was hoping to use an `enum` as a catch all instead of a vector <strings> (still trying to figure out some good options). ie if the string is "+", "-", "/"..., do this generalized code. 100% agree, `Enums` are preferable and more "pretty". But I think the option to check something along the lines of (aVector.contains(aString)) is really nice instead of a bunch of `or`'s. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Concerning Calculator, I once wrote another answer: [SO: Tiny Calculator Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965151/7478597). ;-) Though, it's not so tiny as the name applies and `enum`/`switch` are the least interesting detail.

Answer (score 1):

you can use for char type in C++.

**below works**

```
enum AnOperations : char {
    ADDITION='+',
    SUBSTRACTION='-',
    DIVISION='/'
};
```

**below error in compile time**

```
enum AnOperationsSTR : std::string {
    ADDITION = '+',
    SUBSTRACTION = '-',
    DIVISION = '/'
};
or
enum AnOperationsSTR : char[] {
    ADDITION = '+',
    SUBSTRACTION = '-',
    DIVISION = '/'
};
```

so, you can use like below.

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("is %c == AnOperations:'+' : %s\n", '+', AnOperations::ADDITION == '+' ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    printf("is %c == AnOperations:'+' : %s\n", '+', AnOperations::SUBSTRACTION == '+' ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
    return 0;
}
```

result of above code is,

```
is + == AnOperations:'+' : TRUE
is + == AnOperations:'+' : FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, you cannot switch on a string, but you could **use a map** to achieve the same outcome. Depending on your purpose, it might be overkill.

```
void f( const char* s )
{
  using function_t = std::function< void() >;
  using string_to_function = map< string, function_t >;

  static string_to_function m =
  {
    {"1234", f_1234}, // assosciate "1234" to function f_1234
    {"ABCD", f_ABCD}, // assosciate "ABCD" to function f_ABCD
  };

  auto i = m.find( s );

  return i == m.end()
    ? f_default() // not found in map
    : i->second(); // found, so we call the function
}
```

[Demo](https://www.ideone.com/wPCEiv)

And, **just for fun**, try this:

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int i )
{
  switch ( i )
  {
  default: cout << "default"; break;
  case 'ABCD': cout << "ABCD\n"; break;
  case '1234': cout << "1234\n"; break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  f( '1234' );
  f( 'ABCD' );
}
```