# Checking Enum variable for invalid value in c++

Tags: c++, enums, undefined-behavior, clang++

Consider the following code.

```
//We use c++ version 98.

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//declaration of this enum type is in C header file.
typedef enum Color {
    Red=1, 
    Blue=11
} Color;

//Signature of this function can't be changed
int func(Color c){
    //Following line causes UndefinedBehaviour in clang++ if 
    //value is not a valid Color value
    return (int)c;
}

int main(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << func((Color)x) << endl;
    return 0;
}

//Compilation:
//clang++ -fsanitize=undefined main.cpp
```

Now we want to check if value of `c` in `func` is valid and also want to avoid "Undefined behaviour". But we do not have any control over the caller of the `func`.

**Note** that the declaration of `Color` is in `C` header file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if enum value is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969233/how-to-check-if-enum-value-is-valid)

Comment: @AdrianMole No. I know which values will cause undefined behavior but I don't know how to check it in function `func`. Just even accessing enum variable `c` in `func` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: I just found a way to handle this. `int x = (int)*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&c)` then perform checks on `x`.

Comment: `std::underlying_type<enum>` can inform the type used to store the enum than, you can apply `numeric_limits<>` it will narrow the overflow cases when you are using a enum : char {}...

Comment: _"I just found a way to handle this."_  Not a good way, since that is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Eljay I also had that doubt. That this might cause an undefined behavior. But I was unable to detect it. :)

Comment: Isn’t it the conversion *to* `Color` that might have undefined behavior?

Comment: That's one of the wonders about undefined behavior, it can sometimes appear to work.  Insidious.