# OOP - Is it a good way to override class member variable type

Tags: c++, oop

I have a pre-defined `struct` (unchangable)

```
struct ACCOUNT
{
    char IDAccount[MAX_IDACCOUNT_LENGTH];
    char fullName[MAX_FULLNAME_LENGTH];
    int type;
};
```

Now, I want to override the type of the `type` member variable. Is this a right way doing it?

```
enum ACCOUNT_TYPE {ACCOUNT_TYPE_SV, ACCOUNT_TYPE_CB, ACCOUNT_TYPE_OT};

struct Account : virtual ACCOUNT {
    ACCOUNT_TYPE type;
};
```

Comment: All you're doing is shadowing the base classes member. That's not _'overriding'_ ...

Comment: No. You cannot override types of member variables. There's no good way, no bad way and no any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a right way doing it?

In your second definition you are just *shadowing* `ACCOUNT::type`. There's no way for you to modify the type of `ACCOUNT::type` (unless you modify the actual definition of `ACCOUNT`, which you defined as "unchangeable").

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4165439/493122) if you want to cast the `int` to an `enum` instead.