# using switch in C

Tags: c

I need help please.
I need to design a program that allows a user to enter his or her marks for the coursework and final exams. The program will calculate the final mark and determine the grade gotten. When I tried to run the program, it only went up to the final mark calculation and its not displaying the grades. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

static int count=4;
float testmark[3];
static int i = 4;
static float mark;
float tassmark,assmark,ocm,average1,average2;
int main(){
puts("FINAL SEMESTER GRADE CALCULATOR");
for(count=1;count<5;count++){
float sum;
printf("for test %d you have:",count);
scanf("%f",&mark);
sum= sum+ mark;
average1 = sum/4;
}
printf("\nAverage test mark is %0.2f:",average1);

puts("\n\nTOTAL COURSEWORK MARK CALCULATION:\n");
for(i=1;i<5;i++){
    printf("Enter your mark for assignment %d:",i);
    scanf("%f",&assmark);
    tassmark=tassmark+assmark;
    average2 = tassmark/4;
    }
    printf("\nAverage for assignments is %0.2f:",average2);

puts("\n\nOVERAL COURSEWORK MARK");
ocm=(average1+average2)/2;
printf("\nYour coursework mark is %0.2f:\n" ,ocm);
float exammark,Finalmark;
printf("\n\nEnter your exam mark:");
scanf("%f",&exammark);
Finalmark=(ocm+exammark)/2;
printf("\n\nYou Final mark is %0.2f:",Finalmark);
static char grade='A';
switch(grade){
case 'A+':
    if(Finalmark<=49){
            printf("F");
            printf("FAIL");}
            break;
case 'A':
    if(Finalmark<=53){
        printf("C-");
        printf("Third Class");}
        break;
case '3':
    if(Finalmark<=56){
    printf("C");
    printf("Third Class");
    }
    break;
case '4':
    if(Finalmark<=60){
        printf("C+");
        printf("Third Class");}
        break;
case '5':
    if(Finalmark<=64){
            printf("B-");
            printf("Lower Second Class");}
            break;
case '6':
    if(Finalmark<=69){
      printf("B");
      printf("Upper Second Class");}
      break;
case '7':
    if(Finalmark<=74){
        printf("B+");
        printf("Upper Second Class");
        }
        break;
case '8':
    if(Finalmark<=80){
            printf("A-");
            printf("First Class");}
            break;
case '9':
    if(Finalmark<=90){
            printf("A");
            printf("First Class");}
            break;
case '10':
    if(Finalmark<=100){
        printf("A+");
        printf("DISTINCTION");}
        break;
default:
    printf("You don't have a valid coursework mark");

return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: `'A+'` is not a single character - your compiler should be warning you about this

Comment: yes it is,how can i improve it ?

Comment: Move `float sum;` to above the loop, and change to `float sum = 0;`

Comment: Please apply indentation, it will make some of yoru mistakes much more obvious.

Comment: @PrideSibamba switch on string isn't possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303238/switch-statement-using-string-in-c

Comment: "it only went up to the final mark calculation" what makes you think so?

Answer (score 0):

In the following you:

- declare an integral variable, `grade`, and assign it the numeric value that relates to the character `A` in your platform's encoding (and you declare it `static`, which there's no reason for);
- branch based on the value stored in `grade`, which means you always branch to `case 'A'` because that's the only value you've assigned; and
- print something only if the final mark is less than or equal to 53.

```
static char grade='A';
switch(grade){
...
case 'A':
    if(Finalmark<=53){
        printf("C-");
        printf("Third Class");}
        break;
```

So what you're doing is exactly the same as not using a `switch`, not including any of the other `case`s and not declaring `grade` at all.

`switch` takes an integral value and branches to whichever `case` statement has that value. That's all it does.

Your program appears not have a purpose for a `switch` and it's unclear to me what you were trying to do with it. It looks like you probably just want the `if` statements.