# How use strings in switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, rcpp

How use strings in switch statement? What is the correct syntax? I want to create a menu using the switch statement by the use of strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480788/c-c-switch-case-with-string

Comment: There is no correct syntax because you can't do that. Rethink your solution.