# Strange C behaviour

Tags: c

What is happening here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int x = 'HELL';
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Prints `1212501068`

I expected a compiling error.

Explanations are welcome =)

Comment: So, show us something strange.  We're waiting.

Comment: Haha, you are fun @HotLicks

Comment: Pol0nium, I think that @HotLicks's point was that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and **the expected results**."  Unless you say why `1212501068` is an unexpected result, it's not clear what's supposed to be explained. Granted, you're not asking for code, but the point about the expected results is still a good rule of thumb.

Comment: I've seen this question asked already, but I can't find the duplicate. Anyway, I don't understand why answers to such pointless questions get up-voted so much.

Comment: @sashoalm answers don't get up-voted for being something not answered elsewhere, they get up-voted for being correct. If the question is over-asked, it should be easy enough to get it closed as a dup (though if east answers for undeserved up-votes is your concern, I don't think a closed question prevents credit for the votes).

Comment: You say you expected a compiler warning, but what command line switches did you pass to the compiler?

Answer (score 13):

`1212501068` in hex is `0x48454c4c`.

- `0x48` is the ASCII code for `H`.
- `0x45` is the ASCII code for `E`.
- `0x4c` is the ASCII code for `L`.
- `0x4c` is the ASCII code for `L`.

Note that this behaviour is implementation-defined and therefore not portable. A good compiler would issue a warning:

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:4:11: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

Comment: Indeed.  But is this defined behaviour?

Comment: It's implementation-defined. :-)

Answer (score 9):

In C, single quotes are used to denote characters, which are represented in memory by numbers. When you place multiple characters in single quotes, the compiler combines them in a single value however it wants, as long as it documents the process.

Looking at your number, 1212501068 is 0x48454C4C. If you decompose this number into bytes, you get `48` or 'H', `45` or 'E' and twice `4C` or 'L'

Comment: "..does its best to combine them in a single value". This is optimistic. Since the behavior is implementation-dependent, the compiler could just choose to map every "multichar" constant to the value `-2` (thus not very useful). The only constraint is that it **must document its behavior**.

Answer (score 3):

The output of 1212501068 as hex is: `0x48 0x45 0x4C 0x4C`

Look it up in an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), and you'll see those are the code for `HELL`.

**BTW:** single-quotes around a multi-char value are not standardized.
The exact interpretation of single-quotes around multiple characters is Implementation-Defined.  But it is very common that it either comes out as a Big-Endian or Little-Endian integer. (Technically, the implementation could interpret it *any way it chooses*, including a random value).

In otherwords, depending on the platform, I would not be surprised to see it come out as:
`0x4C 0x4C 0x45 0x48`, or `1280066888`

And over on [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165131/c-c-switch-for-non-integers/18592322#18592322), and also on [**this site**](http://www.terathon.com/wiki/index.php/Simple_Actions_-_%27Hello_World%27_redux) you can see practical uses of this behavior.

Comment: I also haven't seen single quotes used to capture multiple letter word ...

Comment: I struggle to agree that that's a *practical* use...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:  I've seen it used in fast protocol parsers several times.  For example:  Honeywell Barcode scanners communicate using 3-letter commands.  These commands are human-readable, and can still be `switch-case`d as ints very quickly.   Not always pretty, but definitely effective.

Comment: No, it is not UB. It is implementation-defined. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Others have explained what happened. As for the explanation, I quote from C99 draft standard (N1256):

> #### 6.4.4.4 Character constants
>
> [...]
>
> An integer character constant has type `int`. The value of an integer character constant containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. ***The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined.*** If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with type char whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type int.

The emphasis on the relevant sentence is mine.

Answer (score 1):

Line:

```
int x = 'HELL';
```

save to memory hex values of 'HELL' and it is 0x48454c4c == 1212501068.

Comment: This is an obscure feature of the language, and many books on it may overlook the feature completely. Even for those books that happen to address it, other than reading them cover to cover, how would you suggest locating the feature in the book's index?

Comment: @mah Look under "character constant" because that's what it is called in the C standard.

Comment: @Jens I looked in the index of two C/C++ texts from my university days, neither of which listed "character constant". I also looked at the Amazon link posted by MichaelChovanec and used Amazon's "Look Inside" feature to go to its index... missing there too. The point of my first comment was that being part of a language standard is in no way meaning all (or most) good books on the language will document it -- especially with obscure features like this. Your comment (that is, the results when testing it) seem to reinforce that point.

Comment: Why recommend C++ books for a question about C?

Answer (score 0):

The value is just 'HELL' interpreted as an `int` (usually 4 bytes).

If you try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    union {
        int x;
        char c[4];
    } u;
    int i;

    u.x = 'HELL';
    printf("%d\n", u.x);
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("'%c' %x\n", u.c[i], u.c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You'll get:

```
1212501068
'L' 4c
'L' 4c
'E' 45
'H' 48
```

Comment: The value is implementation-defined. -1 for not mentioning that.

Comment: @KeithThompson: if you're going to downvote every answer that doesn't cite chapter and verse, you're going to have your work cut out for you.

Comment: I don't. The fact that the value of `'ABCD'` is implementation-defined is the most important thing to know about it. Someone relying on your answer would assume that it's portable.

Comment: Someone relying on my answer without heeding compiler warnings deserves everything they get.

Comment: Compilers are not obliged to warn about multicharacter constants. Are you really suggesting that it's ok to give incomplete and misleading answers because the compiler will warn about it?

Comment: My answer provides a compact code example that illustrates perfectly clearly how the value that he observed comes about, which was (IMHO) missing in other answers, and thus contributes to the reader's understanding of the issue. At the time of writing, there was *already* a comment on another answer that the multi-character constant was implementation-defined, so how would my repeating that again make any useful contribution? In all honesty, I thought I was a hell of a pedant, but you take the cake.

Comment: IMHO each answer should stand on its own, unless it explicitly refers to other answers. (Thanks for the cake, it was yummy!)

Comment: It's better with cream cheese on it.