# C++: alternative to switch using wstring

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Is there any alternative to use `switch` using a `wstring` in C++? In Java it's no problem - `switch` accepts `String`.

Comment: Yep, an if/else block.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's not very convenient..

Comment: There is no switch on strings in C++. The language does not support that.

Comment: Indeed. However, alternatives are often less convenient - as is the case (pardon the pun) here. :)

Comment: Nothing nearly as simple as a language supported switch statement, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165131/c-c-switch-for-non-integers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ you can only switch on integral types. That's by design and to be able to switch on strings would complicate (or *break*) the language.

There are flashy alternatives such as creating maps of strings to numbers and switching on the latter, but they only obfuscate.

Don't fight the language. Just use `if`, `else if` and `else`.

Comment: I'm used to it in Java. OK, I will :)

Comment: IMHO switching on strings in Java was the start of a few terrible decisions. Having default implementations in interfaces (Java 8) trumps it though. Before then, that terrible date library. And whose idea was it to zero-base the months?

Comment: @Bathsheba: zero-based months were already used in C, so it might be K&R.  To be honest, I never liked that idea either, somebody explained that zerobased month was more convenient to index month name arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only a few cases, then go with if-else blocks.

With more than 5 cases, i'd use a `std::unordered_map` (`#include <unorered_map>` or `#include <tr1/unordered_map>`) with `std::wstring` as keys and `std::function` as value (this way you can use lambda if you don't want to write lone functions).