# How to use array of structures in while loop

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have created a typedef structure as shown below which consists of 4 fields
and i have inserted as array of structures which can be seen below

```
typedef struct Signal {
    long vr;
    char name[20];
    char Type[20];
    char casuality[20];
} Signal;
```

I have used array of structures as shown below

```
void xmlRead()
{
    int i;
    Signal var[4];
    var[0].vr=1073741824;
    strcpy(var[0].name,"Ball1_pos");
    strcpy(var[0].Type,"Real");
    strcpy(var[0].casuality,"output");

    var[1].vr=1073741825;
    strcpy(var[1].name,"Ball2_pos");
    strcpy(var[1].Type,"Real");
    strcpy(var[1].casuality,"output");

    var[2].vr=1073741826;
    strcpy(var[2].name,"Ball1_vel");
    strcpy(var[2].Type,"Real");
    strcpy(var[2].casuality,"output");

    var[3].vr=1073741827;
    strcpy(var[3].name,"Ball2_vel");
    strcpy(var[3].Type,"Real");
    strcpy(var[3].casuality,"output");

    for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        while(var[i].casuality="output") **//Here it is showing error as expression must have modifiable lvalue//**
        {
            //Some statements
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's nothing about array processing and `while` loop, it is just that you try to assign a `(const char *)` value (a pointer to an anonymous `char` array `"output"`) to the `char [20]` variable `casuality` in the `i`-th item of your `var` array. Same error will arise for a standalone declaration `char casuality[20];` and an assignment `casuality = "xxx";` Confusion of assignment `=` and comparision `==` is another problem, and yet another is 'comparing` string characters with ordinary `==` operator (which doesn't work for char arrays as you would expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

Its showing error because you are assigning(i assume u meant to compare here) the base address of the array `casuality` to the string `"output"`

Another thing is you cannot use `==` to compare strings because it will always compare the base address of the two strings and not the contents.

So, to compare the contents, you should use `strcmp()`. So your while loop will look something like this will look like this.

```
while(strcmp(var[i].casuality, "output") == 0)
```

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: mistake, corrected, thanx

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant the answer is correct or wrong

Comment: the same procedure should be followed in switch statement also right.?

Comment: `strcmp` returns `0` *when the strings are identical*. You inverted the condition here.

Comment: @PrajwalBhat: You cannot use strings in a switch statement without some extra work.. Switch statements should have integers only

Comment: @haris what is the work has to be done in order use string in switch statement lets say in the program i want to switch on type as shown below  var[i].Type=Real means i have to do some work and var[i].Type=Integer means i have to do some other work like that

Comment: @PrajwalBhat: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165131/c-c-switch-for-non-integers

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function `strcmp` to compare string in C and loop like this :

```
while (strcmp(var[i].casuality,"output") != 0)
```

The condition in your loop is an affectation, not a comparaison between two string.