# C programming problem with a switch statement

Tags: c

I have a problem with a switch statement.
I tried many of different ways to handle it and I also googled it and I can't find a solution for probably a basic mistake.

Errors:

```
switch(dnevi) -> switch quantity not an integer
case "Pet" -> case label does not reduce to an integer constant
case "Sob" -> case label does not reduce to an integer constant
```

Code:

```
char dnevi[5];
printf("Vnesi dan:\n  P–ponedeljek, T–torek, S–sreda,C–cetrtek, Pet–petek, Sob–sobota, in N–nedelja" );
scanf("%d", dnevi);
switch(dnevi)
{
    case 'P': 
        printf("To je ponedeljek");
        break;
    case 'T': 
        printf("To je torek");
        break;
    case 'S': 
        printf("To je sreda");
        break;
    case 'C': 
        printf("To je cetrtek");
        break;
    case 'Pet': 
        printf("To je petek");
        break;
    case 'Sob': 
        printf("To je sobota");
        break;
    case 'N': 
        printf("To je nedelja");
        break;
    default: 
        printf("Vnos je bil napacen!");

}
```

Comment: You can't use strings as `case` labels. Also strings are usually written insif `""` and not `''`. But you have other problems too. You read `dnevi` as an integer, but storing in `char` array and comparing with characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++: switch for non-integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165131/c-c-switch-for-non-integers)

Comment: 'Pet' and 'Sob' should be something like 'p' and 's'. And you must scanf("%c", ch) character.

Comment: C string literals are *always* written with `""`, not `''`.  A sequence of characters enclosed in `''` is a character constant, with type `int`, not in any way a string.  That's why you can use character constants as case labels, but the resulting behavior is unlikely to be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

It seems in addition to the single character matches, you also want to match against a string. So, you are trying to read a string as input. Simple error handling is illustrated, you may want something fancier.

```
if (scanf("%4s", dnevi) != 1) {
    strcpy(dnevi, "?"); /* simple error handling */
}
scanf("%*[^\n]");       /* get the rest of the input */
```

However, as the error states, you need to provide an integer to `switch`. You can do so on the first character.

```
switch(dnevi[0])
```

However, you now have to deal with the fact you have two `P` choices and two `S` choices. Handle that with special cases in those particular cases. String literals are surrounded by `"`.

```
case 'P': 
    if (dnevi[1] == '\0')
        printf("To je ponedeljek");
    else if (strcmp(dnevi, "Pet") == 0)
        printf("To je petek");
    else
        printf("Vnos je bil napacen!");
    break;
...
case 'S': 
    if (dnevi[1] == '\0')
        printf("To je sreda");
    else if (strcmp(dnevi, "Sob") == 0)
        printf("To je sobota");
    else
        printf("Vnos je bil napacen!");
    break;
...
default: 
    printf("Vnos je bil napacen!");
```

Comment: You also probably want to add some error checking to check the rest of the contents of the strings.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: The `strcmp` is exact match, not prefix match. I added other error checking though, thanks.