# my code doesn't work as expected where i want to run the result of operation what is the problem?

Tags: c

my code doesn't work as expected where i want to run the result of operation what is the problem?
run results told me "compiler error" but i can't find the mistake

```
int main(void) {

int operation,num1,num2;

printf("please enter operation (sum,sub,mul,div) : ");
scanf("%d",& operation);
printf("please enter two number: ");
scanf("%d%d",& num1,& num2);



switch (operation)
​{
    case sum :
      printf("The summation is : %d", num1+num2);
      break; 
    case sub :
      printf("The submition is : %d", num1-num2);
      break;

    case mul :
      printf("The multiplication n is : %d", num1*num2);
      break;

    case div :
      printf("The division is : %d", num1/num2);
      break;

    default:
      printf("Not valid");
}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "compiler error" means that your code is not correctly written and cannot be properly compiled.

Comment: what is the reason?

Comment: You seem to be missing one or more `#include`s. Are you sure you don't need them?

Comment: If you get compiler errors you cannot even try to run. Usually reading compiler errors turns out extremely helpful. If you want us to read them, then please show them here, as full, verbatim quotes in text form. Make sure to identify the mentioned lines. Line numbers are not helpful. So please add `// first error`, `// second error` ...

Comment: There are multiple reasons... you're trying to `switch` over non-existing case variables, you are trying to read a string inside an integer...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C/C++: switch for non-integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165131/c-c-switch-for-non-integers)

Comment: One problem:  You're asking the user to enter a string, and then you are trying to use the scanf %d to save it to an integer variable.

Comment: If you get compiler errors, you should post the exact error message

Comment: Hey Sara, please try to extract the specific problem you are having and use that as a thread title instead, so that future users having the same problem can find your question and any solutions.

Comment: Also "compile error" always shows more information such as the error itself, and what line it happened on. This information is rather crucial to help out and debug.

Comment: Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve] and then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: error:use of undeclared identifier

Answer (score 5):

Add the following:

```
#define sum 1
#define sub 2
#define mul 3
#define div 4
```

and:

```
printf("please enter operation (sum - 1, sub - 2, mul - 3, div - 4) : ");
scanf("%d",& operation);
```

Now the switch statement should work.

Comment: unfortenatlly doesn't work

Comment: Sara, "doesn't work" is not enough information to help you. What is the error message of the compiler or what is the problem you experience now?

Comment: the same problem compiler error

Comment: Sara, the question is WHICH compiler error? What is the message?

Comment: error:use of undeclared identifier

Comment: Now Sara, to be able to help you further, I need to know on which line or which identifier. And don't give me the line _number_ because I am not going to count the lines of your code. I do not have a Magic Crystal Bowl and I cannot read your mind.

Comment: thank you so much it works successfully 2

Answer (score -1):

If that is literally your code, `sum`, `sub`, `mul`, `div` are variables that you did not declare.
Keep in mind that you are comparing `operation` with these variables. It will work if these are all declared and all of them have values (hence the switch control structure).

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int operation,num1,num2;

printf("please enter operation (sum,sub,mul,div) : ");
scanf("%d",& operation);
printf("please enter two number: ");
scanf("%d%d",& num1,& num2);

#define sum '+'
#define sub '-'
#define mul '*'
#define div ':' //careful with special character '/''

switch (operation)
 {
    case sum:
      printf("The summation is : %d", num1+num2);
      break; 
    case sub :
      printf("The submition is : %d", num1-num2);
      break;

    case mul :
      printf("The multiplication n is : %d", num1*num2);
      break;

    case div :
      printf("The division is : %d", num1/num2);
      break;

    default:
      printf("Not valid");
}
```

this is because `case` structures must evaluate **constants**, not variables...

EDIT: sorry, also check for input formats %d is for number, so it should have been 1,2,3,4 instead of +,-,*,/ - thank you @Paul Ogilvie

Comment: `operation` is read with `%d` so won't recognize `'+'` etc.

Comment: 100% correct! I just tested to compile, did not execute, thanks for the comment. @PaulOgilvie