# How to write a switch statement for strings in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, switch-statement

I need to create the equivalent of a switch/case statement for strings in C++ with Qt. I believe that the simplest way is something like this (pseudo code)

```
enum colours { red, green, blue };
QString array[] colour_names = { "red", "green", "blue" };
switch (color_names[user_string]) {
  case red: answer="Chose red";
  case green: answer="Chose green";
  case blue: answer="Chose blue";
  other: answer="Invalid choice";
}
```

But this doesn't take advantage of some of the features of Qt.  I've read about QStringList's (to find the position of the string in a list of strings), and std:map (see [How to easily map c++ enums to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207976/how-to-easily-map-c-enums-to-strings) which I don't fully understand).

Is there a better way to do a switch on strings?

Comment: don't you want to use the enum?

Comment: You cannot use strings in a switch statement. You haven't told us why you need a swicth statement. The most simple solution to a lookup based on a string is to use a map. In Qt it would mean using a QMap<QString,QString>.

Comment: You should use the llvm::StringSwitch: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/StringSwitch_8h_source.html

Comment: I found a suggestion on another site to use a QStringList of colors, use IndexOf() in the switch, and then use the enum value in the case statements

Comment: You can do it with `QMetaEnum` and `QMetaObject` like in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25873662/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to use `switch()` with strings is to use an integer-valued hash of a string. You'll need to precompute hashes of the strings you're comparing against. This is the approach taken within qmake for reading visual studio project files, for example.

Important Caveats:

1. If you care about hash collisions with some other strings, then you'll need to compare the string within the case. This is still cheaper than doing (N/2) string comparisons, though.
2. `qHash` was reworked for QT 5 and the hashes are different from Qt 4.
3. Do not forget the `break` statement within your switch. Your example code missed that, and also had nonsensical switch value!

Your code would look like the following:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int, char **)
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
    static const uint red_hash = 30900;
    static const uint green_hash = 7244734;
    static const uint blue_hash = 431029;
#else
    static const uint red_hash = 112785;
    static const uint green_hash = 98619139;
    static const uint blue_hash = 3027034;
#endif

    QTextStream in(stdin), out(stdout);
    out << "Enter color: " << flush;
    const QString color = in.readLine();
    out << "Hash=" << qHash(color) << endl;

    QString answer;
    switch (qHash(color)) {
    case red_hash:
        answer="Chose red";
        break;
    case green_hash:
        answer="Chose green";
        break;
    case blue_hash:
        answer="Chose blue";
        break;
    default:
        answer="Chose something else";
        break;
    }
    out << answer << endl;
}
```

Comment: OK  cool answer.  How did you get your hash constants?  (Do you have to run a simple program once to print them all out?)

Comment: Yes, you can write a little program that will pick them out for you from source code. Maybe I'll add it to the question later.

Answer (score 2):

```
QStringList menuitems;
menuitems << "about" << "history";

switch(menuitems.indexOf(QString menuId)){
case 0:
    MBAbout();
    break;
case 1:
    MBHistory();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a suggestion on another site to use a QStringList of colors, use IndexOf() in the switch, and then use the enum value in the case statements