# C strings in a switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to switch on a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014827/best-way-to-switch-on-a-string-in-c)

What is the general approach that is being used for strings (c character arrays) together with a switch statement? I'm querying my database for currencies that are stored as

```
"USD"
"EUR"
"GBP"
```

and so on. Coming from a PHP background, I would simply do:

```
switch ($string) {
  case "USD":
   return "$";
   break;
  case "EUR":
   return "€";
   break;   
  case "GBP":
   return "£";
   break;
  default:
   return "$";
}
```

In C the case-value has to be an integer. How would I go about implementing something like that in C? Will I end up writing lots of strcmp's in a huge if/else block? Please also note that I cannot simply compare the first characters of the currencies as some (not in this example though) start with the same character.

Comment: Thanks Cody, haven't seen this one even though I did a search before posting my question.

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165131/c-c-switch-for-non-integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be defining an array of C strings, and use it as a definition of your ordering:

```
const char *currencies[] = {"USD", "GBP", "EUR"};
```

Now you can search `currencies` for your string, and use its *index* in a switch statement.

You can get fancy and - sort your strings, and use [`bsearch`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/bsearch/) to find the index in `O(LogN)`

Comment: The C standard library comes with a `bsearch()` function that can be used for the purpose of finding a string in an ordered array by passing strcmp as the comparator.

Comment: I think that this approach is the best because it feels "clean". I posted a solution here: http://pastebin.com/21jpeLkh

Comment: I would be glad if you could have a look and tell me if this is what you had in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: My other idea was to simply encode all the currencies as numerical values in the db. This of course only works for this specific case.

Comment: @user1288263 Yes, your pastebin source is precisely what I had in mind. In the specific case of currencies you can use (yet) another trick - think of a 3-letter currency code as an *integer in base-26 notation*. You can write a function to convert from base-26, and define integer preprocessor constants for converted codes of currencies that you would like to process.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer in many languages is an *associative container* of some kind; `std::map` in C++, for example. There's a C implementation of an associative array in Glib: see [here.](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) There are other libraries that have their own.

Comment: @Tibor: as I said, Glib has an implementation for C, but perhaps I should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use an if statements for this case with `strcmp` function.