# C - Static array of structs with string member not properly initialised?

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, initialization

Alright, so here goes. I am trying to do a switch over a string value in C, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4014981/962603). However, the array of structs does not seem be initialised properly. My (simplified) program looks as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BADKEY     -1
#define VALUE       1
#define OTHERVALUE  2
#define FOOVALUE    3

#define NREQKEYS (sizeof(lookuptable)/sizeof(symstruct_t))

typedef struct {
    char *key;
    int val;
} symstruct_t;

static symstruct_t lookuptable[] = {
    { "some value here", VALUE },
    { "other value",     OTHERVALUE },
    { "yet another one", FOOVALUE }
};

int main(void) {
    // Testing...
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NREQKEYS; i++) {
        symstruct_t *sym = lookuptable + i * sizeof(symstruct_t);
        printf("%d: key = '%s', val = %d.\n", i, sym->key, sym->val);
    }
}
```

Then, I compile the above program as follows (it is saved in `test.c` obviously), on Debian Jessie (currently testing). The version of gcc is `gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)`. Compiling gives no warnings or errors.

```
gcc test.c -o test -std=gnu99
```

Now, I would expect that this simple program simply prints out the values that I initialise the array with. However, the output is this:

```
$ ./test 
0: key = 'some value here', val = 1.
1: key = '(null)', val = 0.
2: key = '(null)', val = 0.
```

The two possible causes I can think of are that either my loop is incorrect, which makes no sense to me, or that the initialisation somehow is wrong. However, searching this site and in general on Google did not help me. I am open to other solutions as well, but also interested in just *why* this does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: `char *key` should be `char key[SIZE]` It should be array not pointer.

Comment: Navnath, I cannot do that as the strings will have different sizes. Also, that was not the problem :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression is wrong:

```
lookuptable + i * sizeof(symstruct_t)
```

It's enough with

```
lookuptable + i
```

The compiler already knows the size of each member in the array, so it knows that adding `i` to the array means that it will use index `i`, i.e. it's the same thing as `&lookuptable[i]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer (it works!) and the explanation. As soon as I can (have to wait 5 minutes), I will accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to *scale* the pointer to the size of the object that it points to `lookuptable + i * sizeof(symstruct_t);` ; the compiler does that for you automatically.

`ptr+1` will be interpreted by the compiler as a pointer to the *the next object* after `*ptr` ; if `ptr` points to the first array element, `ptr+1` will point to the second.

```
for (i = 0; i < NREQKEYS; i++) {
        symstruct_t *sym
        sym = lookuptable + i;
        printf("%d: key = '%s', val = %d.\n", i, sym->key, sym->val);
    }
```

Or, its equivalent:

```
for (i = 0; i < NREQKEYS; i++) {
        symstruct_t *sym
        sym = & lookuptable[i];
        printf("%d: key = '%s', val = %d.\n", i, sym->key, sym->val);
    }
```

BTW: you don't **need** a pointer here, array indexing will work just fine:

```
for (i = 0; i < NREQKEYS; i++) {
        printf("%d: key = '%s', val = %d.\n", i, lookuptable[i].key, lookuptable[i].val);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I wil use the second option in my program.

Answer (score 2):

You should drop the `sizeof(symstruct_t)` coefficient. C and C++ pointer arithmetic does this automatically for you.

To help understand this, remember that pointer arithmetic and array access are the same thing:

`Array[i]` is the same as `*(Array + i)`

It would be inconvenient to have to write `Array[i * sizeof(...)]` and therefore equally inconvenient if you had to write `*(Array + i * sizeof(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
symstruct_t *sym = lookuptable + i * sizeof(symstruct_t);
```

should be

```
symstruct_t *sym = lookuptable + i;
```