# How to switch a string in C?

Tags: c, string

How to use strings in a switch statement? For now I used the first letter of the string in the switch statement. Here is my code. I want to use the whole string in char a, b, c as the input in switch. How to?

```
int main()
{
    char input[10];
    int x, y, i;
    int AX;
    char a[] = "ADD";
    char b[] = "PRT AX";
    char c[] = "EXIT";

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("\nType ADD following the two numbers to be added\n");
        printf("     PRT AX to display the sum\n");
        printf("     EXIT to exit program\n");
        printf("---->");
        scanf("%s", &input);

        switch (input[0])
        {

        case 'A':

            printf("\nEnter two numbers you want to add:\n");
            scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
            break;
        case 'P':
            printf("Sum: %d\n\n", x + y );
            break;
        case 'E':
            exit(0);
        default:
            i++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only `switch` over integral values in C.  Use multiple `strcmp`s in an `if`, `else if` cascade, grouping the likely cases near the beginning.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014827/best-way-to-switch-on-a-string-in-c (It's a question that is closed as some people think that it is unclear. Seems very clear to me.)

Comment: @Bryan Reyes Do not be hurry. See my answer.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char input[10];
    int x, y, i;

    const char * a[3] = 
    {
        "ADD",
        "PRT AX",
        "EXIT",
    };

    enum CHOICE { ADD, PRT_AX, EXIT, WRONG } choice;

    for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        size_t n;
        printf( "\nType ADD following the two numbers to be added\n" );
        printf( "     PRT AX to display the sum\n" );
        printf( "     EXIT to exit program\n" );
        printf( "---->" );
        fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin );

        n = strlen( input );
        if ( n && input[n-1] == '\n' ) input[n-1] = '\0';

        choice = ADD;
        while ( choice != WRONG && strcmp( a[choice], input ) != 0 )
        {   
            choice = ( enum CHOICE )( choice + 1 );        
        }

        switch ( choice )
        {
        case ADD:
            printf( "\nEnter two numbers you want to add:\n" );
            scanf( "%d %d", &x, &y );
            fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin );
            break;
        case PRT_AX:
            printf( "Sum: %d\n\n", x + y );
            break;
        case EXIT:
            puts( "Exiting..." );
            exit(0);
        default:
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also take into account that you should read wntire line using `fgets` and then apply `sscanf`.

Comment: Can't display the sum when I typed PART AX.

Comment: @Bryan Reyes  First of all in your code there is PRT AX instead of PART AX. Nevertheless the problem is that you are trying to enter two words while scanf scns only one word, As I wrote in my answer you have to use fgets instead of scanf if you want to use more than one word as input.

Comment: consider using a n-sized array of const char* instead of char a[3][10], since all arguments are string constants. Less memory use, more safety in case one of a later set of arguments is longer than 10 chars. ex: const char *a[3] = {"hello", "world", "bye"};

Comment: @midor I used arrays because in the original post there are also arrays.":)

Comment: @Vald: yup, but those are not limited in size, since the compiler will determine the right size at compile time. Also seems like a bad design decision from OP to use arrays there. Would make it possible to swap the argument that triggers add and exit at runtime in your code. Seems like the OP is doing this for exercise only, so it won't matter, but I think we should try to point him into the right direction right away.

Comment: @Bryan Reyes It seems you did not copy and paste the code correctly.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Hi, is it possible to input like this? "ADD 4,5" 
What I mean is that your ADD input is with the two numbers, not separating each other. Can you make it?

Comment: @Bryan Reyes Yes, it is possible. Only then you need to use sscanf to extract each data from the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The C11 standard is very clear about what may be allowed in switch statements:

> 6.8.4.2 The switch statement
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 The controlling expression of a **switch** statement shall have
>   integer type.
>
> [...]
>
> 3 The expression of each **case** label shall be an integer constant
>   expression and no two of the **case** constant expressions in the same
>   **switch** statement shall have the same value after conversion. ...

<sup>Note: characters have integer type in C.</sup>

Instead, you want to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare strings. **Do not use the comparison operator**! `strcmp` will return `0` if two strings are equal.

Comment: Not assignment `=`, right, but ***also*** not the comparison operator `==` (which gets (ab)used at least as often than a simple `=`).

Comment: @Jongware I derped on that one.

Comment: Okay.Thanks. I'll try the strcmp.