# C INPUT of Switch Case

Tags: c, input, switch-statement

how to input String and use it in the Switch command? Here is the code but I get switch quantity not an integer error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float usd2 = 0.9117;
    float yen2 = 0.0073;
    float pound2 = 1.4137;
    float eingabe;
    char whr[] = "";

    printf("Bitte Summe in EURO eingeben: ");
    scanf("%f", &eingabe);
    printf("Die Währungnummer eingeben USD, YEN, POUND: ");
    scanf("%s", &whr);

    switch(whr) {
        case "usd": printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f USD.", eingabe, (eingabe/usd2));
        break;
        case "yen": printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f YEN.", eingabe, (eingabe/yen2));
        break;
        case "pound": printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f POUND.", eingabe, (eingabe/pound2));
        break;
        default: printf("Falsche eingabe.");
        break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first question should be "Is it possible?". The answer is "no".

Comment: You can't. You can only switch on integer values.  You'll have to use if/else and strcmp.

Comment: You have no room for `whr`

Comment: first `char whr[] = "";` --> `char whr[6/* or more */] = "";`

Comment: [best way to switch on a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014827/best-way-to-switch-on-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Note that you should restructure the code so that you have an array of structures so that you can find the appropriate conversion factors with a search, rather than hard-coding the list of currencies and values.  OTOH, that is probably still beyond what you've learned, so it isn't so much of a problem as yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way in C to use a "string" (an array of characters in your case) in a switch statement's condition or in the label constant expressions as they cannot be converted to an integral value. C requires the condition and the constant expressions to be of integral type (cf., for example, [this online c++ standard draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.2)):

> **6.8.4.2 The switch statement**
>
> 1 The controlling expression of a switch statement shall have integer
>   type.
>
> ...
>
> 3 The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
>   expression ...

To overcome this, you could use cascades of `if (strcmp(whr,"USD")==0) else if (strcmp(whr, "YEN")==0)...` or you could introduce an enum that represents the currencies and map the user input to such enums.
As the `if-else`-cascades are straight forward, I just show the second approach. Using enums has the advantage that you can use them easily throughout your program without the need of repeating the `if-else`-cascades at different places in your code:

```
typedef enum  {
UNDEFINED, USD, YEN, POUND
} CurrencyEnum;

struct currencyLabel {
    CurrencyEnum currencyEnum;
    const char *currencyString;
} currencyLabels[] = {
    { USD, "USD" },
    { YEN, "YEN" },
    { POUND, "POUND" }
};

CurrencyEnum getCurrencyByLabel(const char* label) {

    for (int i=0; i< (sizeof(currencyLabels) / sizeof(struct currencyLabel)); i++) {
        if (strcmp(label, currencyLabels[i].currencyString) == 0)
            return currencyLabels[i].currencyEnum;  // could use strcasecmp or stricmp, if available, too.
    }
    return UNDEFINED;
}

int main(void) {
    float usd2 = 0.9117;
    float yen2 = 0.0073;
    float pound2 = 1.4137;
    float eingabe;
    char whr[10] = "";

    printf("Bitte Summe in EURO eingeben: ");
    scanf("%f", &eingabe);
    printf("Die Währungnummer eingeben USD, YEN, POUND: ");
    scanf("%s", whr);
    CurrencyEnum currency = getCurrencyByLabel(whr);

    switch(currency) {
        case USD: printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f USD.", eingabe, (eingabe/usd2));
            break;
        case YEN: printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f YEN.", eingabe, (eingabe/yen2));
            break;
        case POUND: printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f POUND.", eingabe, (eingabe/pound2));
            break;
        default: printf("Falsche eingabe.");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

BTW: Note that defining `whr` as `char whr[] = ""` actually reserves a string with size 1, and using it in `scanf` yields an overflow (and undefined behaviour). You can define it as `char whr[10]` or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

*C* doesn't really have strings as you see in other, higher languages. Rather, C strings are simply arrays of chars. That means that complex operations like comparison doesn't really work on strings natively.

As they are currently designed, switch statements only operate on a single integer value. This can be represented as either a single char or an int which sometimes causes confusion. To do what you want, you'll need to use `if` and `else if` statements with the `strcmp()` function.

```
if( strcmp(whr, "foo") == 0 ) {
    // do a thing
}
else if( strcmp(whr, "bar") == 0 ) {
    // do a different thing
}
else {
    // default thing to do
}
```

Documentation on [`strcmp()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcmp.php) function and [`if`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/if_else_statement_in_c.htm) statements.

**Edit:**

I've demonstrated a simple two condition statement. In reality, the `else` statement is optional, and you can have as many `else if` statements as you'd like.

You'll also need to include the string header in your program. Do this at the top of your file where you're including `stdio.h`

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: @eXme: as many as you want. I've added an update to address that.

Comment: @eXme: you'll have to give more detail than that for me to help you. This *is* how you compare strings in C.

Comment: 15 23 G:\data\owncloud\Project\C\Training\währung\1.cpp [Error] 'strcmp' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @eXme: You need to include the string header.

Comment: But it compiles if I write if(whr == "USD" )  but no effect at the end it just goes to the else..

Comment: @eXme: I've added an edit that shows how to include the string header. As I've already said in my answer, you can't use `==` with a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151440/discussion-between-jacobm001-and-exme).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    float usd2 = 0.9117;
    float yen2 = 0.0073;
    float pound2 = 1.4137;
    float eingabe;
    char whr[5] = "";

    printf("Bitte Summe in EURO eingeben: ");
    scanf("%f", &eingabe);
    printf("Die Währungnummer eingeben USD, YEN, POUND: ");
    scanf("%s", &whr);

    if( strcmp(whr, "USD") == 0 ) {
    printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f USD.", eingabe, (eingabe/usd2));
    }
    else if( strcmp(whr, "YEN") == 0 ) { // strcmp(1 array, 2 array) wenn die gleich sind gibt der 0 raus, when linke hat weniger char dann negativ und wenn linke größer dann positiv
    printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f YEN.", eingabe, (eingabe/yen2));
        }
    else if( strcmp(whr, "POUND") == 0 ) {
    printf("%.4f EURO es sind dann %.4f POUND.", eingabe, (eingabe/pound2));
        }
    else {
        printf("Falsche eingabe.");
    }


    return 0;
}
```