# Switch, case in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to do switch with cases, but I want to use word instead of number or letter, e.g.

case 'quit': (...)

But I know that C doesn't support it.

Could you tell me how to use 'some word' in case?

Comment: Either calculate a unique ordinal to use in the case-statements or use if-statements.

Comment: You can't, but you could test the word against an array of key words, and use the index of a match as the switch case. Or, you could have words with a unique initial and use that for the switch case.

Comment: Chek [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014827/best-way-to-switch-on-a-string-in-c) out.

Answer (score 1):

A `switch` statement is no more than some optimization to choose among one of a number of options. Any switch statement can be implement as an `if...then...else if...` statement.

The optimization in C is for integers and it cannot handle strings

A witch statement for strings would thus be an `if...then...else if...` statement using `strcmp`, e.g.

```
if (strcmp(a,"hello")==0) {
    //case "hello"
}
else if (strcmp(a,"world")==0) {
    // case "world"
}
else {
    // default
}
```

One difference betwee a `switch` statement and an `if..then..else` statement is that the latter does not know "fall thru" and it cannot be simulated unless using `goto` (which is discouraged).

The comments to your question also suggest more advanced methods than brute force string-compare. All those methods try to use some unique characteristic of your string to translate into some number on which a `switch` can be implemented.