# How can I print the registration number of student according to his/her department and school

Tags: c

Getting issue while solving this problem for assignment of C programming:

Need to create an app for college where there are 500 undergraduate students from which 250 are in School of Engineering (SOE) and 250 are in School of Science (SOE) , where suppose if a student belongs to Computer engineering (CE) batch 2020_21:
supposed output needs too look like:
SOEUNGCE0001 - SOEUNGCE0040

departments in school of engineering are:

1. chemical engineering -CHE
2. computer engineering -CE
3. mechanical engineering- ME
4. Environmental engineering -ENE
5. Electrical Engineering - EE

and in school of science:

1. Architecture  -AR
2. computer science-CS
3. Biotechnology-BT
4. Pharmacy-PH

***I tried printing with switch case statements but it's wasn't working with strings. also the below program is having some issue i.e. it doesn't take some inputs.***
***HELP ME SOLVE THIS.***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char name;
    int roll_no;
    char department;
    char school;
}students;

int main()
{
    students student;

    //inputs
    printf("Enter Name : " );
    scanf("%s", &student.name);
    printf("\nRoll Number : ");
    scanf("%d", &student.roll_no);
    printf("\nDepartment : ");
    scanf("%s",&student.department);
    printf("\nSchool : ");
    scanf("%s",&student.school);

    if (student.department == 'Chemical')
    {
        printf("Name : %s \t",student.name);
        
        printf("\n%sUNG%s00%d", student.school, "CHE", student.roll_no);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `student.department == 'Chemical'`: That's not how you compare strings in C, you can use `strcmp()` for example to compare two strings. Also string literals in C should be within `" "`.

Comment: *it's wasn't working with strings* - `char name;` etc are not strings.

Comment: why can't I give full name as input and how do I use switch case for (string) department and school to give unique registration number as output?

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.   ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.  The following lines do not compile: `if (student.department == 'Chemical')
    {
        printf("Name : %s \t",student.name);
        
        printf("\n%sUNG%s00%d", student.school, "CHE", student.roll_no);`

Comment: @TheNisham If you want to have input with spaces, use `fgets()` instead (or you can also use `scanf("%[^\n]",buf);`, but it's better to use `fgets()` since it has buffer overflow protection). You cannot use switch with strings in C.

Answer (score 1):

**You have 3 mistakes:**

1. Logical Error: since `name`, `department` and `school` are strings, so they must be arrays of characters i.e `char name[100]`. So the structure should be modified as the following:

```
typedef struct{          
    char name[100];      
    int roll_no;         
    char department[100];
    char school[100];    
}students;
```

2- After editing the structure you will get warning from the compiler since `scanf` takes the address of the element to be scanned and `student.name` points to the first character of the string `name`. So Edit the `scanf` arguments to be :

```
scanf("%s", student.name); 
.
scanf("%s", student.department); 
.
scanf("%s", student.school);
```

*Note: You can also use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to avoid buffer overflow but you have to consider that `fgets` includes the newline character, `\n`, within the string, so you have to replace the `\n` with `\0`. See [tricks for how to replace the `\n` with `\0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/10851804)*

3- The last error is in comparing strings, you should use the `strcmp` function to compare between two strings, the function **returns 0** if the two strings are typical. Also the string literals sholud be put inside double quotation marks `""`.  So you should modify the last block to be :

```
if (!strcmp(student.department, "Chemical"))                        
{                                                                   
    printf("Name : %s \t",student.name);                            
                                                                    
    printf("\n%sUNG%s00%d", student.school, "CHE", student.roll_no);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[100];
    int roll_no;
    char department[100];
    char school[100];
} students;

int main() {
    students student;
    char input[100];
    //inputs
    printf("Enter Name : " );
    fgets(student.name, 50, stdin);
    printf("\nRoll Number : ");

    fgets(input, 50, stdin);
    sscanf(input,"%d", &student.roll_no);

    printf("\nDepartment : ");
    fgets(student.department, 50, stdin);
    printf("\nSchool : ");
    fgets(student.school, 50, stdin);

    if (strcmp(student.department, "Chemical") == 0)
    {
        printf("Name : %s \t",student.name);

        printf("\n%s %d", student.school, student.roll_no);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why can't I give full name as input and how do I use switch case for (string) department and school to give unique registration number as output?

Comment: I updated the code by changing `scanf`! `scanf` does not handle space properly. For switch case because your string is dynamic it is better to handle it with if-else. You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014827/how-can-i-compare-strings-in-c-using-a-switch-statement too.
@TheNisham

Comment: @G.Emadi Do NOT forget that `fgets` includes the new line character within the string.
so if the user entered `Chemical` the `\n` will be included. So `Chemical\n` is not equal to `Chemical`.