# C switch case using char[2]

Tags: c, switch-statement, ascii, c-strings

I'm trying to use switch case with char[2] in C, but it only supports integers.

```c
int main() {
        char c[2] = "h";
        switch (c) {
                case "h":
                        printf("done!");
        }
        return 1;
}
```

For better understanding, what I'm trying to do is:

```py
if "h" in ")($+#&@+)#"
```

Basically I want to make a condition that matches a character with a group of characters, **but efficiently**, the first thing that came to mind is to use switch case but it only supports int. But when I use `(int)c` which is recommended in other stackoverflow answers, it doesn't return the ascii value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare strings in C using a \`switch\` statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014827/how-can-i-compare-strings-in-c-using-a-switch-statement)

Comment: Wait, you only want to `switch` on a single character? If so, you can just do that: `switch (c[0]) { case 'h': /*...*/`. But there are already standard library functions for searching substrings or characters in strings, so I am not sure what the purpose of the `switch` is.

Comment: no, let's say it's 50 characters, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: you mean "switch(c[0])"

Comment: @user17732522 answering the second question, Thanks! why doesn't it work with double quotes?

Comment: @KapesoftFx Because `"h"` is a _string literal_ of type `char[2]` and `'h'` is a _character literal_ of type `int`.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks! Finally, you had said that there are functions of the standard library that do exactly that, can you mention any function? Something like this will work: `'h' in '+$-h' // true`

Comment: @KapesoftFx `strchr` to search for characters and `strstr` to search for substrings. One of the answers below explains the use of `strchr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare arrays of characters (strings) using a switch statement directly, because switch statements only work with fundamental types; not arrays of fundamental types.

The reason using `(int)c` isn't returning the ASCII value is because you're casting `char[]`->`int` instead of `char`->`int`.

The difference between single and double quotes is an important one in C:

- `'h'` is of type `char`, and is equal to `104` *(Lowercase 'h' in ASCII)*
- `"h"` is of type `const char*`, and points to 2 characters: `h`, & the null terminating character `\0`

To check if a character is present in a string, you can use the [`strchr`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) function as mentioned in [Vlad from Moscow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71105348/8705305), or if you want to do it yourself using switch statements you could try this:

```
int main()
{
    char c[2] = "h";
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        switch (c[i]) {
        case 'h': // compare c[i] == 'h'
            found = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found)
        printf("Done!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the switch statement in this case does not make a sense.

Just use the standard function `strchr` declared in `<string.h>`.

```
#include <string.h>

//...

if ( strchr( c, 'h' ) != NULL ) puts( "done!" );
```