# C - Is there an better way to do this rather than doing all of it manually?

Tags: c, console-application

So I am trying to make an text based game in C and I'm not sure if there is an way to automate doing this:

```
int karte_plans() {
    printf("\n ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬   ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬ ");
    printf("\n┃----------------------------------------------------------------------------┃ ┃              ┃                            ┃               ┃");  
    printf("\n┃********************************** Karte ***********************************┃ ┃   Pilsēta    ┃      Apskates objekti      ┃   EU Stacija  ┃");  
    printf("\n┃----------------------------------------------------------------------------┃ ┃              ┃                            ┃               ┃");   
    printf("\n┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃ ┃              ┃                            ┃               ┃");
    printf("\n┃           *  /             _/     ^___/   /                          `^    ┃ ┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃");
    printf("\n┃             |           __/              |                             |   ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");  
    printf("\n┃              ^___  ____/          .*    |                              |   ┃ ┃     Rīga     ┃       1      ┃      2      ┃       A       ┃");  
    printf("\n┃                _||                      /     ___________            _/    ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");
    printf("\n┃               / /                       |___/             ^        /       ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");  
    printf("\n┃              /_/                       /                  ^   ___/         ┃ ┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃");  
    printf("\n┃                                       |                    ^_/   |         ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");
    printf("\n┃                    .        *          |                          |_       ┃ ┃    Tukums    ┃       3      ┃      4      ┃       B       ┃");  
    printf("\n┃                __/  |                  |                            `      ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");  
    printf("\n┃             __/      `_                 |                           |      ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");
    printf("\n┃ Ventspils /X            `               |                            |     ┃ ┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃");  
    printf("\n┃          /  |` _   Talsi `_             |                             |    ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");                                                            
    printf("\n┃         |    |  ` X__       `          /                               `_  ┃ ┃    Talsi     ┃       5      ┃      6      ┃       C       ┃");  
    printf("\n┃         |     |      `       `        /   __X Sigulda                    | ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");  
    printf("\n┃       /Kuldīga X      X Tukums` _____/  _/                               | ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");
    printf("\n┃     /           |     `_       _X______/                                  |┃ ┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃");  
    printf("\n┃    |             `     `_     /  Rīga                                    | ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");  
    printf("\n┃   | Liepāja   ____`X______`X_/                                           | ┃ ┃   Ventspils  ┃       7      ┃      8      ┃       D       ┃");
    printf("\n┃   |X_________/  Saldus       Jelgava       ^                              |┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");  
    printf("\n┃   |                                      /  ^                            | ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");
    printf("\n┃   |          _________ ___________  ____/     ^___                      |__┃ ┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃");  
    printf("\n┃   |      _/ `         `           ``              `__                 _/  ^┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");
    printf("\n┃    |  __/                                            `__             /     ┃ ┃   Liepāja    ┃       9      ┃      10     ┃       E       ┃");  
    printf("\n┃    | /                                                   `___   ___/       ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");  
    printf("\n┃    |'                                                        `|`           ┃ ┃              ┃              ┃             ┃               ┃");
    printf("\n┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃ ┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬┃");
    char izv[1][1];

    printf("\nIzvēlies nākamo staciju: ");  
    scanf("%s",izv);  
  
    switchs(izv)  {  
        icases("A")  
            main();  
        break; 
  
        icases("B")       
            palidzība();  
        break;  

        icases("C")  
            main();  
        break; 
  
        icases("D")       
            palidzība();  
        break; 

        icases("E")  
            main();  
        break; 
  
        icases("1")       
            palidzība();  
        break;  

        icases("2")  
            main();  
        break; 
  
        icases("3")       
            palidzība();  
        break;  

        icases("4")  
            main();  
        break; 
  
        icases("5")       
            palidzība();  
        break;  

        icases("6")  
            main();  
        break; 
  
        icases("7")       
            palidzība();  
        break;  

        icases("8")  
            main();  
        break; 
  
        icases("9")       
            palidzība();  
        break;  

        icases("10")       
            palidzība();  
        break;
  
        defaults  
            printf("Kļūdaina ievade, ieraksti jebkuru burtu vai skaitli, kas rādīts tabulā.");
        karte_plans();
        break;  
    } switchs_end;
}
```

What I am trying to do is allow the player to move only to control points that are 1 square around him so if the player is in the "6" square then he would be able to move to the "3", "4", "B","C", "D", "8", "7" and "5" square like the king in chess and blank out the remaining ones with an asterisk.With an switch statement (The one here is just an slightly modified one for strings) It can be done manually but that would take a long time for all the options and wouldn't be very efficient.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: a graph? used for generating the rest of the map?

Comment: What is `icases()`? Does that generate the `case XXX:` labels in the switch?

Comment: @Barmar No, It's an function that allows to use strings in an switch. icases() just means that it's case insensitive. You can find it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605146/18621162)

Comment: It's a macro: `#define icases(x)`

Comment: And now I see that this isn't actually a `switch` statement, it's using that `switchs()` macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the board as a 2D array. 1 is `[0][0]`, 2 is `[1][0]`, A is `[2][0]`, 3 is `[0][1]`, 6 is `[1][2]`.

Each element would be a struct with information about that square. What it's named. What's in it. Etc.

Find legal moves by adding and subtracting 1 from both x and y and making sure they're within the bounds of the board. You can do this with a for loop.

```
for(int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
  int x = player_x + dx;
  if(x < 0 || x > max_x) {
    // Out of bounds
    continue;
  }
  for(int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
    int y = player_y + dy;
    if(y < 0 || y > max_y) {
      // Out of bounds
      continue;
    }

    // board[x][y] is legal
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array like int array[width][height][symbol].
Then i would design my art in a .txt file and let a method translate it into the array. An other method would than print the whole thing.